# Does android has something like onDate listener?

Tags: android, time, listener

Is there any way in Android to make some action when a certain date is reached ? Something like a listener that is activated when an specific date is reached.

For example, I want to call a method or something when the day is the number 8 or it is 20/12/2012. Does Android provide something like that or I have for example to test every 'x' seconds if I have reached the date I wanted ? I think that would waste resources and should be a better way of doing it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to set an alarm for midnight on the day you are watching for, using [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: Yes it seems to be the right solution, but for example if I am at day 2 11:59PM and 1 minute later it is day 3 12:00AM the event is not launched, but if in day 3 I set the alarm to day 3 it is launched, why ?

Comment: The event should be launched at midnight. What intent are you associating with the alarm event? Are you using a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the alarm event? Show your code.

Comment: Thank you I didn´t realized that, yes I am using a BroadcastReceiver I got it working :) Nice utility thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

there is an intent action called ACTION_DATE_CHANGED. i don't know exactly when it's fired, but you could make a broadcast receiver to catch it and see if it gets fired at midnight.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

Comment: I tried it but it is only fired when I change the date manually in Android settings

Comment: then i would guess that no, there isn't an event fired for what you are looking for.